# How to express "patronizing" in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, words, word-requests

Not in the sense of giving money as a patron to an artist or something like that, but the sort of attitude one gives when they superior to someone else. All the examples I can find are super figurative, and the only thing I can think of that I've actually ever heard is 上から見る　but I'm wondering if there are any alternatives, or even one-word examples that express this.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few:

・上{うえ}から目線{めせん}の ← Very common for the last decade or two.

・（人{ひと}を）見下{みくだ}したような

・お高{たか}く留{と}まった

・横柄{おうへい}な

・恩人{おんじん}ぶった

・恩着{おんき}せがましい

There are more and which one to select would solely depend on the context/situation.

Comment: Thanks so much! Would you be able to describe some of the nuances?